# Issue with Telerik RadMenu and web.config Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radmenu

Whenever I add a `domain` tag to the web.config `Forms` section it makes my menus disappear from my application.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="appname" loginUrl="login.aspx" domain="localhost" />
</authentication>
```

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 1):

This prevents all requests under this application from passing unless you authenticate. For aspx pages this is fine and dandy, but for the webresource requests AJAX controls needs this is a problem, because IIS does not return the scripts/stylesheets, but the error page.

So, add a location element to provide access to the needed handlers:

```
<configuration>
...
<location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="*"/>
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </location>
...
</configuration>
```

Or, turn on the CDN so webresources are used as rarely as possible:
http://www.telerik.bg/help/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager-cdn-support.html and http://www.telerik.bg/help/aspnet-ajax/stylesheetmanager-cdn-support.html. The MS AJAX scripts, however, will still be taken from webresource, I think. Take a look at the requests in the browers and let the needed ones pass.